# AOSP compiled image for Nexus 9 doesn't boot

Tags: android, android-source

Hi has anybody tried to compile Android 5 on Nexus 9? I manage to compile it fine but then when I flash it it doesn't boot. Tried loads of different approaches, nothing.

Re-synced the tree, started from scratch, rebuilt, etc, nothing.

If I use the factory images everything works.

I noticed that during the AOSP build the vendor.img (included in the factory image) is not generated. Is that the issue? No idea how to solve that though, since I followed the build instructions to the letter.

I'm out of options. Any help?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

<s>For some reason there's still no AOSP device drivers for Nexus 9:
https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers</s>

For other Nexus devices (4/5/6 etc) there's drivers but for Nexus 9 there is nada.

Looks like Motorola (or some of the device component vendors) did not want to release the drivers for Android developers. You need device drivers e.g. for BT, NFC, Camera, Sensors, Audio, Wi-Fi, Graphics, Cell Modem, Camera, GPS, USB etc).

For this reason you can build the AOSP for Nexus 9 but it really might not work out as expected since the device drivers are missing.

The binaries are actually "missing" due to this:

https://plus.google.com/+JeanBaptisteQueru/posts/akHWypRNEn3

http://ausdroid.net/2014/11/08/nexus-9-proprietary-binaries-required-aosp-builds/

So Nexus 9 should work with AOSP without extra driver hassle.